# How to enable “remember me” checkbox in WooCommerce login forms by default?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce login form. I have added WooCommerce shortcode `[woocommerce_my_account]`. But i want to enable remember me" checkbox on login forms by default. I tried lot of plugin to solve my problem E.G [Remember Me Controls](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remember-me-controls/) & [Remember Me](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-remember-me/). But nothing works. Even i put question in [wordpress development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/323492/155370) but did not get any relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about wordpress but in html you can do:

Adding a "checked" attribute at last will set the checkbox checked by default.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to wp-includes > plugins > woocommerce > templates > myaccount
2. Open form-login.php
3. Search for this line:

```html
<input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" />
```

4. Replace it with following:

```html
<input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: This will be overwritten with the next update, always consider copying the templates in a child theme before modifying them...