# Woocommerce form-login remember me checked by default

Tags: authentication

i found this help already and it works fine:
[How to enable “remember me” checkbox in WooCommerce login forms by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880568/how-to-enable-remember-me-checkbox-in-woocommerce-login-forms-by-default)

Go to wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > templates > myaccount
Open form-login.php
Search for this line:

Replace it with following:

But please, how to add it as a snippet, or in a child theme (for at next woocommerce update, to not lost it)

thank you

But please, how to add it as a snippet, or in a child theme (for at next woocommerce update, to not lost it)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `form-login.php` into your theme and make you changes there. It will use that version from your theme instead of the one from WooCommerce. You will need to check your version on update in case the WooCommerce one has changed to port in any changes that are relevant?

From the `form-login.php` file:

```
This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php.
```